# How can I properly use methods from a class in another class in C# Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c#, forms, visual-studio-2010, methods, treeview

So, I have a Form2 with the method public void LoadTree() (which loads data from a database onto a TreeView in Form2), I also have a Form3 that starts on a button click from Form2. In Form3 on a button click (after some code executes) I want to use the LoadTree() method from Form2.

I have the following code in Form3 to do this:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var loading = new Form2();
        loading.LoadTree();
        loading.Show();
    }
```

All works and executes well,no errors, but at the end of this I have a Form2, a Form3, and another Form2, If i try to put a code to close the first Form2, the entire program shuts down, what could I do about it?, I just want that after I click the button on Form3, Form2 to show as updated.

Comment: That is because a form (basically a class) is not a single instance by default. You are instantiating multiple instances of `Form2`. You could look at singletons for a start if that is what you are trying to create... Alternatively store the instance of `Form2` somewhere and keep using that.

Comment: It may not seem much but better, meaningful naming will make both describing your problem and answering it easier.

Comment: Maybe this won't work for you, but what about just hiding and then re-showing form2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have a Form2 with the method public void LoadTree() (which loads
>   data from a database onto a TreeView in Form2

Do not make database calls directly in a form.  Put this code in another class, better yet use n-tier.

> In Form3 on a button click (after some code executes) I want to use
>   the LoadTree() method from Form2.

And

> I just want that after I click the button on Form3, Form2 to show as
>   updated.

Form3 raises the event which is to be handled by Form2.  Best practice is to use events for communicating messages across forms.  You could use a property here, but this would be a side effect of a property and thus not a good way to accomplish the goal.

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{        

    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void LoadTree(Object o, EventArgs e)
    {
        //do work
        MessageBox.Show("Loading tree...");
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var form = new Form3();
        form.LoadTreeEvent += form_LoadTreeEvent;//Hook into the Form3 event 
        form.Show();
    }

    void form_LoadTreeEvent(object o, EventArgs e)
    {
        LoadTree(o, e);//Handle Form3 Event
    }
}

public partial class Form3 : Form
{
    //The event is raised by Form3, however it's handled by Form2.
    public event LoadTreeHandler LoadTreeEvent;        
    public delegate void LoadTreeHandler(Object o, EventArgs e);

    public Form3()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LoadTreeEvent(null, null);//Raise the event in Form3 and pass whatever
        //do work...maybe close this form??
    }
}
```

Comment: Indeed there was a problem with Sudhakar Tillapudi's provided solution, I still had that form opening again problem when I logged in and out of the program (it also has a login/logout feauture), I modified the program with your solution @P.Brian.Mackey and everything seems to be ok so far, no bugs. Thankyou very much, I should've tested the first solution more before I makred it as answer, now I'll mark your post as solution since it's the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

**Problem :** You are creating the newinstance of `Form2` (or whichever Form you want to show) everytime, so that it creates a **new instance** everytime and all your old changes will notbe available.

**Solution :** Don't create a new instance of `Forms` which are hidden while switching between the different Forms,rather open the already existing `Form2` from Memory using the `Application.OpenForms[]`

Try This:

```
Form2 form2 = (Form2) Application.OpenForms["Form2"];

//now use form2 variable
form2.LoadTree();
form2.Show();
```